# SaveChanges над группой объектов vs над каждым

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Допустим, есть цикл, который идет по 1000 объектов, каждая итерация цикла что-то меняет в объекте.

Собственно вопрос, а когда лучше выполнять SaveChanges?

На каждой итерации цикла или дождаться конца цикла и сохранить 1000 объектов?

Comment: Даже из самых общих соображений -- лучше в конце цикла. Так у Entity Framework появляется возможность что-то оптимизировать при выполнении сохранения.

Answer (score 3):

Подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) задавался на англоязычном сайте.

1. Лучше всего делать один вызов `SaveChanges` на 1000 объектов. Чем чаще вы вызываете SaveChanges, тем ниже производительность. 
   Если посмотреть ответ @Slauma на тот вопрос, то он провел эксперимент и выяснил, что самая лучшая скорость сохранения большого количество объектов(1000000), когда вы создаете новый контекст и делаете один вызов метода SaveChanges над этим контекстом на среднее количество объектов(например 1000, зависит от памяти). 
   Почему среднее? Потому что если вы попробуете сохранить очень большое количество объектов(например, сразу же 1000000), то большая вероятность, что вы нарветесь на исключение [OutofMemoryException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), так как ваш контекст будет содержать большое количество притаченных(буферизированных) объектов в контексте и производительность будет падать.
2. когда вы сохраняете 1000 объектов, то они сохраняются в БД в одной транзакции. Если не удалось сохранить хотя бы один объект, то остальные тоже не будут сохранены. То есть при одном вызове метода нет необходимости создавать отдельную транзакцию.

Answer (score 0):

1000 объектов - это достаточно мало, чтобы принимать во внимание затраты памяти на трекинг изменений.

Если вы проводите одну общую операцию над 1000 объектами, которая должна быть атомарной - вам нужен один вызов `SaveChanges()`, который или сохранит все изменения, или не сохранит ни одного.

Если вы проводите 1000 независимых операций над каждым из объектов, при этом результаты уже проведенных операций должны быть сохранены вне зависимости от успешности следующих - вам нужны отдельные вызовы `SaveChanges()` (но стоит учесть что 1000 отдельных запросов в базу может занять достаточно много времени).